# (MOBILE) Image optical recognition to count number of items

Tags: android, mobile, count, image-recognition

I am wondering how to do as I said in the title:

I want to have some objects counted reading an image from the camera of the portable device (such as iPhone or Android phones)

I need only two specific functions.

1. Recognize and count the amount of objects
2. Recognize the color of the object (so I can count how many of each color I have).

A very simple example.

I have a stack of pieces of LEGO, all of them the same dimensions. I know they always will be aligned horizontaly, sometimes they are not verically aligned. I need to count how many of each colour I have.

I know that I have pieces with the same dimensions, only the colour change.
I have i think only 10 colour avaible.

I can elaborate the image (such as blur and other stuff) but I don't know how to read how many pieces I have.

Can you tell me some Ideas how to do (and what kind of libraries to use both for iOS and Android -android first-) or maybe some publication (free pdf or books or even publicated books even if they're not free) teaching how to read data from images.

The program should be act as the same:

I start the program, when the program recognize it is looking at (using the integrated cam) some specific objects, ittake a picture and elaborate it, telling how much of each color I have.

Thanks in advance, ANY kind of help will be

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit it is 10 years since I last dabbled with computer vision, but back then I used the OpenCV libraries, and these still seem to be going strong, and support on Android:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android

and iOS:

http://www.eosgarden.com/en/opensource/opencv-ios/overview/